# Can I save PIL image array into Qt?

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt, pyside, python-imaging-library

I want to save PIL image.
I tried to do it by pickle and I could make it.
For example, I want to save it by `QtCore.QDataStream`.

Can I do it?

Here is the original code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import pickle

filename = 'Any_Image.png'

im = Image.open(filename)
data = np.array(im)

f = open("test_file.dat","wb")
print(type(data))
dumps = pickle.dump(data,f)

f = open("test_file.dat","rb")
tumps = pickle.load(f)
array = Image.fromarray(tumps)
array.show()
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the "on hold " problem. As the result, Nishant Patel  please understood my intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do similar thing with QDataStream, just that you need to convert the image numpy **array to bytes**

Here's a simple implementation:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore

filename = 'Goku.jpg'

im = Image.open(filename)
data = np.array(im)

file_ = QtCore.QFile("test_file.dat")
file_.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
qdatastream = QtCore.QDataStream(file_)
bytedata = QtCore.QByteArray(data.tobytes())

print(qdatastream)

qdatastream << bytedata
```